# What value does Solidity return if a record is queried that doesn't exist?

Tags: solidity

If you have a function querying a flat file record:

> ```
> function getData(address _storageContract) constant returns(uint256){
>
>     return dataStorage(_storageContract).getUIntValue(sha3("RecordID"));
>
> }
> ```

and this RecordID doesn't exist: What is the value returned by Solidity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value will be `0`. Solidity doesn't make any distinction between a zero value and a nonexistent value.